# Making trivial things big, and big things trivial

Tags: terminology, literary-device

In Sherriff’s play *Journey’s End*, Sherriff makes a recurring point of soldiers ‘coping’ with the war by **making trivial things big and big things small**, so much so that deviation from this theme leads to stress among characters.

Is there a name for this technique? What are the advantages of this technique to evoke pathos, as used in literature more generally? I can imagine this technique being used in satirical works, but I am primarily interested in non-satirical works like Sherriff's, as I am more interested in how this technique evokes *pathos* than humour.

Comment: You may be looking for the rhetorical devices of [auxesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxesis_(figure_of_speech)) and [meiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis_(figure_of_speech)).

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I don't really have any idea to make an answer, I only made an edit to clarify the question. Hopefully Gareth can answer.